# onmouseover events and smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scroll

I have an html notification view with a scrollbar.

Each notification of the list reacts to onmouseover to display a little toolbar.

When the user scrolls, the scrolling experience is not smooth due to these onmouseover events that are fired during the scrolling.

How can I make the scroll smoother? Should I try to deactivate the onmouseover when user is scrolling? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: If your `onmouseover` events are _that_ heavy on the browser, you should really look into what's causing the delay. Are you manipulating the DOM in the event? Could you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Even if the onmouseover was lighter, that would probably impact a little the scrolling experience. I can defenitively make it lighter but would prefer keep things like they are today because of how I use ReactJS (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxN8FYYBcrI): a onmouseover triggers a full React rendering

Comment: can you lazy load your `onmouseover` event? so if pointer is on notification for 250 ms then open toolbox, else do nothing.

Comment: Yes probably anyway that is a bit similar to disabling onmouseover